# Changing QCadmin password in Quality center

Tags: quality-center

We have changed the qcadmin password with the help of our DBA. It is not the default password now. 
As the password is changed at DB level do we need to update the password in qc ALM server and any other table in the DB?

I remember when we changed the password in Performance center,I had to update password in siteconfig file in ALm server and  DBSERVERS table.

Please let me know what need to be done for Quality center.

Thanks,
vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made few changes to db and ALM server than the issue was resolved. Looks like there is a difference if the DB users set if based on the DB used(Oracle/SQL). Our PC is using Oracle DB.
1. QCadmin password changed at DB level.
2. QCsiteadmin password at DB level.
3. Updated the password in DB table DBServers under QCSiteadmin schema.Update both qcadmin and sa_db_host.
4. Updated the QCsiteadmin password in ALM server path ProgramData\HP\ALM\webapps\qcbin\WEB-INF